# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-chartjs-2'

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using chart.js v4.0.1 and react-chartjs-2 v5.0.1 and when i try to import react-chartjs-2 in my js file, it shows that module is not found.

```
import React from "react";
import {Line} from "react-chartjs-2"

function LineChart({ chartData }) {
  return (
    <div className="chart-container">
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Test Line Chart</h2>
      <Line data={chartData} width={500} height={350} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default LineChart;
```

I also added this line in my package.json, as per this [instruction](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/migration-to-v5)

```
{
  "type":"module"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you install the libraries

```
npm install --save chart.js react-chartjs-2
```

check:[here](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/#quickstart)

Comment: I did, I used Chart.js in another file as react-chartjs-2 requires chart.js in order to work.